# TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable on Euler's method LTE calculation

Tags: python, typeerror

Before anything, sorry any sppeling, english issues, english is not my mother tongue.

I'm doing an assgment on Euler's Method to calculate ODEs, and in the calculatrion of the LTE(Local truncation error) I keep receiving this error:

> TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable

I took a look at previous questions with the same subject, but I didn't find exactly what I was looking for. Below the code for the euler's method and the error calculation.

```
def euler(f,y0,a,b,h):
    t,y = a,y0
    vet_s = np.array([])
    vet_err = np.array([])
    while t <= b:
        #print t , y
        vet_s = np.append(vet_s, y)
        t += h
        y += h * f(t,y)
        vet_err = np.append(vet_err, erro(yn, y, t))    # The problem is here
    return vet_s, vet_err

def y(t, y):
    return lbd*y

def yn(t):
    return np.exp(-1*t)

def erro(yn, un, t):
    erro_local = abs(yn(t) - un)
    return erro_local
```

When I call the error calculation inside the *vet_err* assigment function I receive the error displayed above.
I think that it's a simple fix, but i can't find it myself.

The main call for the Euler's method is this:

```
h = 30./60.
lbd = -1.0
t = np.arange(0, 30, h)
sol = erro = np.array([])
sol, erro = euler(y, 1.0, 0.0, 30.0, h)
```

Is there any syntax, code issue? Also any pointer in order to improve the code would be of great help. Thanks.

Comment: How are you invoking this function? What is the arguments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some issues I see in your code -

1. I am assumming you have defined the function named `erro` first and then afterwards you are also doing -

   ```
   erro = np.array([])
   ```

   This causes the name `erro` to point to a `np.array` , which is what is causing the issue you are having, you should use a different name here , maybe something like `erro1` (or some other good meaningful name).
2. Then in the function - `euler(f,y0,a,b,h)` - you are defining variable with name - `y` . But there is also a `y` function outside, (This does not directly cause issues, since you passed the reference to function y as the first argument to this function) .

   But I would advice against doing this (As you may encounter issues later on). Always use different meaningful names, I do not think there is a shortage of words/letters in English for use :) .
3. Also there is no need to do -

   ```
   sol = erro = np.array([])
   ```

   Since you reassign it to return value of `euler()` functio in next line, you do not need to even define them before that (unless you want to use them , which does not seem like the case).

Comment: Thank you, this solved my problem, I'm a python newbie and I overlooked it and again, thanks for the code improvement advices.